# How to work with dataset's datarelation in linq?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, linq, ado.net

Can someone provide an example of linq querying various nested tables in a dataset? I can't find something like that on the net.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't you just navigate?

```
from cust in ds.Customers
from order in cust.GetChildRows("CustomersOrders").Cast<Order>()
```

etc?